# webpack ts-loader not excluding files

Tags: typescript, webpack

I have the following webpack rule setup for typescript.

```
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: [
          /node_modules/,
          /server/gi,
          path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/server.ts'),
          path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/server.worker.ts'),
          path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/network/ServerNetwork.ts'),
        ],
        use: {
          loader: 'ts-loader',
          options:{
            compilerOptions: {
              module: "esnext"
            }
          }
        }
      },
```

When I run webpack I get an error that indicates one of the excluded files is being processed.

```
ERROR in /Users/kevzettler/code/hypeworks/src/server.worker.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kevzettler/code/hypeworks/src/server.worker.ts(96,3)
      TS2304: Cannot find name 'subscribeToMasterMessages'.
```

I would expect this not to be an issue because this webpack config should be excluding this file . Why is my `exclude` condition not being met?

the `path.resolve`s expand to absolute paths that are valid files

```
console.log(
  path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/server.ts'),
  path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/server.worker.ts'),
  path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/network/ServerNetwork.ts')
);

/Users/kevzettler/code/hypeworks/src/server.worker.ts
```

Comment: what happens if you renames those 3 files to some different extensions, say, *.tsp

Comment: does this work for you https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/544

Comment: If I rename the 3 files to *.tsp it compiles without error.

Comment: @ABOS i've tried a few different variations from that github issue with no success

Comment: can you try to put exclude in tsconfig.json?

Comment: It works in `tsconfig.json` @ABOS feel free to leave an answer. This appears to be a known problem with `ts-loader`.

Comment: ok, answer created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [ts-loader doc](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#onlycompilebundledfiles),

```
The default behavior of ts-loader is to act as a drop-in replacement for the tsc 
command, so it respects the include, files, and exclude options in your tsconfig.json,
loading any files specified by those options.
```

So it should work by adding **exclude** in tsconfig.json.